# Get user's input to create a text triangle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

So I wanted to have 2 text field where users choose which symbol to use in creating their triangle.
So the user input a size, let's say 4, then chooses `#` as first row and input any symbol as the second row, it will look something like this:

```
#
gg
###
gggg
```

I've done it with only 1 pre-set symbol for all the row to be as:

```
#
##
###
####
```

I just don't know how to set it so user chooses which one to be presented, any help? Here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/u6mjm/2/

Comment: Read about `%` (modulus) operator. Normally the description would be here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators but at the moment there are some issues on MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the acquisition of the second value:

```
var secondChoice = customJS.get("secondChoice").value;
```

You can also change `createLine` to accept a second argument that is the symbol to print.  To determine which symbol, just check whether `i % 2` is truthy:

```
var oneLine = createLine ( i, i % 2 ? firstChoice : secondChoice );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/u6mjm/3/

Comment: 1 more question. I know that `?` is a ternary operator, but what if I want to use `if else` instead? So would `var oneLine = createLine ( i, i % 2 ? firstChoice : secondChoice );` becomes `var oneLine = createLine (i, if (i % 2) {createLine = firstChoice; else createLine = secondChoice; } )` ? I've tried to do that in jsfiddle but doesn't work.

Comment: @KennyWong that's syntactically incorrect because you can't have the `if` expression inside of a function call.  You need to move the `if` to before the function call and store the symbol you want in a variable